# Cannot Retrieve Query from Current User - Parse (Android)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve an image from the current user to display as a profile picture.

I can quite easily get it to work by inserting a specific object ID after `query.getInBackground()` What I want to do is to pull the "profilePicture" of the user currently logged in, hence current User, and not just one specific user. How can I fix this?

```
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(GalleryActivity.this, "",
                "Downloading Image...", true);

        // Locate the class table named "ImageUpload" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // Locate the objectId from the class

        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        query.getInBackground(String.valueOf(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()),
                new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {

                    public void done(ParseUser object,
                                     ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        // Locate the column named "ImageName" and set
                        // the string
                        ParseFile fileObject = (ParseFile) object
                                .get("profilePicture");
                        fileObject
                                .getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {

                                    public void done(byte[] data,
                                                     ParseException e) {
                                        if (e == null) {
                                            Log.d("test",
                                                    "We've got data in data.");
                                            // Decode the Byte[] into
                                            // Bitmap
                                            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                                                    .decodeByteArray(
                                                            data, 0,
                                                            data.length);

                                            // Get the ImageView from
                                            // main.xml
                                            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.galleryProfilePic);

                                            // Set the Bitmap into the
                                            // ImageView

                                            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 300, 300, true);
                                            Bitmap conv_bm = getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, 300);

                                            image.setImageBitmap(conv_bm);

                                            // Close progress dialog
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                                        } else {
                                            Log.d("test",
                                                    "There was a problem downloading the data.");
                                            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.galleryProfilePic);
                                            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_default_profile_picture);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: At the first query you query the user again and get back the some object as the currentUser. The currentUser.equals(object) returns true, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this working by passing the object ID of the current user as a string into the query to replace the static object ID:

```
String currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
query.getInBackground(currentUser,
        new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
```